# (T-SQL) Clustered vs Non-Clustered in this Scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I am soon to be taking an exam and I am doing some practice questions:

> You are creating indexes in a data warehouse.
> You have a dimension table named Table1 that has 10,000 rows. The rows are used to generate several reports.
> The reports join a column that is the primary key.
> The execution plan contains bookmark lookups for Table1.
> You discover that the reports run slower than expected.
> You need to reduce the amount of time it takes to run the reports.
> Solution: You create a non-clustered index on the primary key column that includes the bookmark lookup columns.
> Does this meet the goal?

Yes or No

> Extra Question: The following question asks the same question as above but with a clustered index instead of a non-clustered. What would this answer be?

My thoughts: The answer could be yes for both of them, since it's possible to speed up the query by using both methods. If there's no clustered index then adding one will improve performance. And if we use a non-clustered index we can include covering columns etc. which will also speed up the query.

Comment: The `join` is already on the primary key.  For a table of that size, I wouldn't expect any other indexes to have a noticeable affect on performance.  I would look for performance improvements somewhere else.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the options are just Yes or No. Are you saying that you'd go yes for clustered, no for non-clustered?

Comment: The wording is a little bit vague.    However yes to the non-clustered index with included columns.    However if the follow up is suggesting that you create a Clustered index with Included columns then No - since you cannot have included columns in a clustered index.   The quality of some of these practice exams frustrates me at times.

Comment: This question has no bearing on reality. So, reading the clues in the question, they probably want you to remove the bookmark lookups. Bookmark lookups happen when rows are found in a non clustered index, but you still need to go to the actual row to find a field value (that isn't in the CI). If you were to create a NCI that "INCLUDE" these missing fields it could certainly help. But the question doesn't say that.